# How to get cell reference value in particular column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset. In that I have to add a new column. The value of this new column will come from the **mu** and **timepoint** columns.  If **mu** contains **ae** and **timepoint** contains **1** then it will take the value of number **1 from ae** and so on.

Dataset description
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Also, please don't upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: I do not see any time points in your picture.

Comment: Do you mean to do the operation that's described in your picture? (@danlooo, I think "timepoint" is meant to be column AH in the diagram ...)

Comment: Yes you are right